# Visual Studio Code(macOS version) -- How to zoom out edit interface like JetBrain iDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, editor, zooming

I know there has a way to zoom out/in by `cmd + shirt + +/cmd + -`,

but I just want to zoom out edit interface not complete interface, and can zoom in/out by sliding two fingers splay likes JetBrains iDE.

How to config my Visual Studio Code? (note: I want not to install any extensions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `editor.action.fontZoomIn` (`editor.action.fontZoomOut`) command. By [default](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf) this command **is not bound to any keyboard shortcut**.
You can open and edit the keyboard shortcuts by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.
Instead you also can edit the `keybindings.json` directly, for instance like this:

```json
{
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+oem_plus",
        "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn",
        "when": "editorFocus"
    }
}
```

I am not aware that vscode supports multi touch gestures. Maybe somebody else knows an issue reference or you may want to [open your own issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=feature_request.md).

Comment: It's surprising there is no keybinding for this action by default. I can confirm this also works for Codespaces as I was recently doing an online course and the editor font size was massive and I was struggling to find how to reduce the editor font size.